# Is it possible to configure Gmail to reply to forwarded email using the original address?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

Suppose I own `bar.com` and have `foo@bar.com` forward to my `foobar@gmail.com` gmail.

Suppose someone writes to `foo@bar.com`.

I will pick it up in gmail webclient `foobar@gmail.com` account.

But my reply will appear as being from `foobar@gmail.com`.

Can I configure Gmail so that the reply will automatically appear as being from `foo@bar.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is it possible to configure Gmail to reply to forwarded email using the original address?"*

Yes. You need to create an alias first.

Go to `Settings` >> `Accounts and Import` >> `Send mail as:` >> `Add another email address`.

Once created you will find additional options on how to reply to your emails at [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).

[image]